# Twitter share - redirects urlencode param %2C to %252C

Tags: twitter, urlencode

I'm using the twitter custom share button 'Build your own tweet button' (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button).
The documentation says that I have to use the query parameters to pass on params.

**PROBLEM:** Twitter is encoding the text param wrong when I pass it a URL encoded string. A comma (,) is displayed as %252C in the tweet message. Other chars are also wrong encoded.

I use PHP url encode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to prepare the string for the call.

```
$text = urlencode("I just backed ". $project->getTitle().", an amazing new mobile app, on appbackr, where anyone can back mobile apps");
```

Then I build the twitter link:

```
'http://www.twitter.com/share?url='.urlencode($projectUrl).'&via='.$via.'&text='.$text.'&related='.$user->getTwitterProfileName()
```

The final twitter url call is:

```
http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fapp%2Fbig-top-ballet&via=appbackr&text=I+just+backed+Big+Top+Ballet%2C+an+amazing+new+mobile+app%2C+on+appbackr%2C+where+anyone+can+back+mobile+apps&related=philippberner
```

As soon as the page opens in the browser (Chrome and Firefox) twitter redirects the URL to:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?related=philippberner&text=I+just+backed+Big+Top+Ballet%252C+an+amazing+new+mobile+app%252C+on+appbackr%252C+where+anyone+can+back+mobile+apps&url=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fapp%252Fbig-top-ballet&via=appbackr
```

This displays the following message in the tweet box:

> I just backed Big Top Ballet%2C an amazing new mobile app%2C on appbackr%2C where anyone can back mobile apps via @appbackr

It converts *Top+Ballet%2C+an+amazing* to *Top+Ballet%252C+an+amazing*. The comma is displayed properly when I manually change %252C to %2C in the twitter URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing much to do with url encoding.

It actually works with urlencode, with rawurlencode, or even without url encoding
Try the following URLs on opening a new tab.

**With urlEncode**: http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.appbackr.com%2Fapp%2Fglass-ceiling&via=appbackr&text=I+just+backed+Glass+Ceiling%2C+an+amazing+new+mobile+app%2C+on+appbackr%2C+where+anyone+can+back+mobile+apps&related=

**With rawurlEncode**: http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.appbackr.com%2Fapp%2Fglass-ceiling&via=appbackr&text=I%20just%20backed%20Glass%20Ceiling%2C%20an%20amazing%20new%20mobile%20app%2C%20on%20appbackr%2C%20where%20anyone%20can%20back%20mobile%20apps&related=

**Without urlEncode**: http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.appbackr.com%2Fapp%2Fglass-ceiling&via=appbackr&text=I just backed Glass Ceiling, an amazing new mobile app, on appbackr, where anyone can back mobile apps&related=

The trick actually lies in using twitter.com instead of www.twitter.com. Not sure why there is a difference and it does not seem to be documented anywhere in twitter's documentation nor in google's search results. Although to be fair, [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) did point to twitter.com and not www.twitter.com.

As always, it is definitely best practice to always urlencode the text even though it works without url encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$text = rawurlencode("I just backed ". $project->getTitle().", an amazing new mobile app, on appbackr, where anyone can back mobile apps");
```

Then, use this URL:
    'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='.urlencode($projectUrl).'&via='.$via.'&text='.$text.'&related='.$user->getTwitterProfileName()

Comment: With rawurlencode I get even the empty spaces in the url. I tried that before. The difference as I understand is in the encoding of a space. They are not causing the problem. Then the twitter message looks like: I%20just%20backed%20Big%20Top%20Ballet%2C%20an%20amazing%20new%20mobile%20app%2C%20on%20appbackr%2C%20where%20anyone%20can%20back%20mobile%20apps via @appbackr

Comment: This is an error in the URL rewriting of twitter API, it encoding GET data again when it redirect url "http://www.twitter.com/share" to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet". Use this last URL. You also have to use rawurlencode instead of urlencode.